# Updating records with addition using sub queries in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am attemping to update a record in table StockCatalog called Product Quantity by adding Product Quantity together with a record called DeliveryQuantity in table DeliveryContent whilst inner joining two records, StockCatalog.StockID = DeliveryContent.StockID inner joining DeliveryContent.DeliveryID = Deliveries.DeliveryID. So far I have this:

```
    UPDATE StockCatalog
    SET ProductQuantity = (SELECT StockCatalog.ProductQuantity FROM StockCatalog INNER JOIN DeliveryContent on StockCatalog.StockID = DeliveryContent.StockID WHERE StockCatalog.ProductQuantity + DeliveryContent.DeliveryQuantity)
    WHERE (SELECT DeliveryContent.DeliveryID FROM DeliveryContent INNER JOIN Deliveries on DeliveryContent.DeliveryID = Deliveries.DeliveryID)
```

However it appears that this updates all ProductQuantity records in StockCatalog with one record of DeliveryQuantity in DeliveryContent. Sorry If this is confusing.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be some confusion about WHERE going on. I GUESS this is what you want:

```
UPDATE StockCatalog sc SET ProductQuantity = ProductQuantity +
( SELECT DeliveryQuantity FROM DeliveryContent WHERE StockID=sc.StockID )
WHERE StockID in (select StockID from DeliveryContent);
```

If more than one DeliveryContent can exist for each StockID, maybe DeliveryQuantity should be replaced by SUM(DeliveryQuantity).